# Sencha touch for Mobile Web Development

Tags: android

im new at making mobile websites. and I saw sencha touch as it was recommended by most of the people. so i just want to ask you guys if what tools or any experties that i should get to start with. ive already downloaded sencha touch 2.0.1-commercial. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with the getting started guide. This will help you in setting up your environment:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started

Continue with a Hello World: 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/first_app

After this brief introduction you may start getting familiar with MVC application architecture: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/application_architecture

And then you can go on working with using Sencha Architect: 
http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2-0/#!/guide

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

http://jquerymobile.com/

start to here in the future, do not worry

Answer (score 0):

You do need to have knowledge about HTML, CSS and JavaScript-Ajax...These are the prerequisites of Sencha Touch